# installng Ubuntu over XP

Tags: system-installation, windows-xp

Ubuntu 12.04 - booted on my pendrive, trying to boot, but only boot screen appears.

When i select boot from USB then directly windows XP get started.

How to install it?

Is there any driver problem?

Having 1 Gb ram and 40 Gb hard disk PC.

Comment: what tool are you using to make the USB drive bootable?

Comment: UNetbooting software.

Answer (score 1):

May be the case that your pen-drive may not be bootable, try format it once and add ubuntu distribution using 'Universal USB Installer' and go to boot/setup screen and make boot preference as 'boot from USB'

Comment: +1 for Universal USB installer from http://pendrivelinux.net. It is the most user-friendly USB key creator that I've come across and seems to work every single time, unlike Unetbootin. You don't even need to format the USB key first, Universal USB Installer will do this for you. If you have any issues, check your downloaded ISO's md5 checksum with the advertised one on ubuntu.com.

Comment: 0
_s(vote down)
accept
I also used UNetbooting software. & Select usb as boot device in boot preferance.

But same thing going.

Is there any driver problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with UNetbootin, which can be downloaded here: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net. Click on the "Download for Windows" link to download it. It will allow you to make any USB storage device (thumb drives and hard drives) bootable.

Read the FAQs on how to use the application. Good luck and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I also used UNetbooting software.
&
Select usb as boot device in boot preferance.

But same thing going.

Is there any driver problem?